# Ember expand child controller/view

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

How do I structure this to work?

I have Projects which have many notes. Notes are listed using an itemController. I need these notes to have an expanded view which can be toggled by the route (it's the show view for a note inside of the project). How can I get a route to toggle a specific note that's listed on the page to expand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the the official Ember Guides for help: http://emberjs.com/guides/. The example there is with a simple application with many posts (in your case projects) and each post has many comments (in your case notes). The only thing missing is the option to toggle a note, instead of open it permanently.

Using the Guide only, your router should look something like this:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('project', {
        path: '/project/:project_id'
    }, function () {
        this.resource('note', { path: '/note/:note_id' }, function () {});
    });
});


App.ProjectController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    toggle: function(note) {
        var isOpen = !note.get('isOpen');
        if (isOpen) {
            this.transitionTo('note', note);
        } else {
            this.transitionTo('project', this.get('content'));
        }

        this.get('notes').forEach(function(note) {
            note.set('isOpen', false);
        });

        note.set('isOpen', isOpen);
    }
});
```

Then, your project template should list all the notes and provide a place to open a note and view it:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="project">
    {{#each note in notes}}
      <li>
        <button type="button" {{action toggle note}}>
          {{note.name}}
        </button>
      </li>
    {{/each}}

    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="note">
  {{description}}
</script>
```

To clarify things: ProjectController is an ObjectController with a content set to the currently opened project. ProjectController#notes is where all the notes for the currently loaded project will be. 
The project/note.handlebars will simply describe the note, as you desire it to be shown inside the project page.

Here is a working fiddle (with some boilerplate code added): http://jsfiddle.net/ZcspT/6/

EDIT:

Here is the version without routes (only the different parts):

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('project', {
        path: '/project/:project_id'
    });
});

App.NoteView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'note',
    content: null,
    classNameBindings: ['content.isOpen::hidden']
});


App.ProjectController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    toggle: function(note) {
        var isOpen = !note.get('isOpen');
        this.get('notes').forEach(function(note) {
            note.set('isOpen', false);
        });

        note.set('isOpen', isOpen);
    }
});
```

The templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="project">
    {{#each note in notes}}
      <li>
        <a {{action toggle note}} href="#">{{note.name}}</a>     
      </li>
    {{/each}}

    <div id="noteSection">
       {{#each note in notes}}
         {{view App.NoteView contentBinding="note"}}
       {{/each}}
    </div>
</script>
```

The stylesheet:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZfWhc/1/

Comment: The *isOpen* property should be stored in Note Controller, not in the note itself..

Comment: The problem with that is that it's outputting to an outlet. It should just expand the actual note itself to show the details and not put it in an outlet below all the notes.